# Readonly property for RefGuidlist tagged value

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have created a tag value type RefGuid list. Now I want the user to only view not to edit it.So is there any way to provide an option read-only for the tagged value type RefGuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box. You can probably create an add-in that hooks to `EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified`. However, this does not return tagged values but only the container (e.g. `EAObject`). So in order to see what has changed in the tagged values you also need to subscribe to `EA_OnContextItemChanged` to save the current state before eventually the `...Modified` is fired.

Answer (score 0):

You also create an add-in and "subscribe" to the tagged value edit events, see the [manual](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/automation/tagged_value_broadcasts.html) for the different events depending on the tagged value owner.
The tagged value needs be of type AddinBroadcast. When the user tries to edit the tagged value, the event will be triggered and your add-in can handle this.
In the case of read-only the handling will be more of a "not handling".